# Pandas transform with sum takes too long

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has the following columns of integer values:

```
user_id, user_agent_id, appearances
```

Number of rows vary but they are more than 4 hundred thousand. I want to create a new row total appearances which is the sum of all appearances for each user. So I do the following:

```
dataframe['total_appearances'] = dataframe['appearances'].groupby(dataframe['user_id']).transform('sum')
```

I need that because I want to calculate percentage per of user_agent_id per user that is

```
dataframe['percent'] = dataframe['appearances'] / dataframe['total_appearances']
```

I do the same thing to calculate max value of percent

```
dataframe['max_percent'] = dataframe['percent'].groupby(dataframe['user_id']).transform('max')
```

etc.

The thing is while the max method in the transform method takes about 5m the sum method takes far to longer that is 2sec. Is this natural? Is there a faster way to obtain the information of the `total_appearances`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could consolidate the first two lines into one step with something like this:

```
# sample data
df
   appearances user_id
0            6     abc
1            3     abc
2            5     abc
3            8     def
4            4     gfd
5            2     uio
6            1     def
7            8     poi
8            3     fab

df['percent'] = df.groupby('user_id').appearances.apply(lambda x: x.div(np.sum(x)))

df
   appearances user_id   percent
0            6     abc  0.428571
1            3     abc  0.214286
2            5     abc  0.357143
3            8     def  0.888889
4            4     gfd  1.000000
5            2     uio  1.000000
6            1     def  0.111111
7            8     poi  1.000000
8            3     fab  1.000000
```

Do you see a performance improvement with these changes?

Comment: what is `a` method? Sorry it is the column name. Also I have never seen this syntax using a paranthesis on the column name.

Comment: I don't have a problem on calculation the percentage but the total appearance column. The transformation is the problem :). But I will check and come back to you

Comment: Name expected error on the parenthesis. Maybe you are missing a call of a method?

Comment: There is an error in your code `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Apostolos - Updated with your naming convention and fixed typo. Somehow left out `apply` when pasting. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: @Apostolos - Also keep in mind, I'm using sample data so this method might not work with your case. Sample data would be helpful in the future.

Comment: No unfortunatelly  it didn't work any faster. Took abou the same time